# Iterate over JavaRDD<String> in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on **SPARK**. And my objective is to read lines from a file and sorted them based on hash. I understood that we get the file as **RDD** of lines. So is there a way by which i can iterate over this RDD so that i can read line by line. So i want to be able to convert it to Iterator type.

Am i limited to applying some transformation function on it in order to get it working. Following the lazy execution concept of Spark

So far i have tried this following transformation technique code.

```
  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sorting1");

  JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);


  JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/hash-example-output/part-r-00000", 1);




     lines = lines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>()
                {
                  @Override
                  public Boolean call(String s) {
                    String str[] = COMMA.split(s);
                    unsortedArray1[i] = Long.parseLong(str[str.length-1]);
                    i++;
                    return s.contains("error");

                  }
                });

     lines.count();
     ctx.stop();
     sort(unsortedArray1);
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with above code? what is unsortedArray? do you want to sort the lines? or the value within a line?

Comment: @Averman I want store line by line in the array. And then send it to the sort function

Comment: So, the sorting is outside of spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort string in RDD, you could use takeOrdered function

> **takeOrdered**
>  java.util.List takeOrdered(int num,
>                               java.util.Comparator comp) 
> Returns the first K elements from this RDD as defined by the specified
>   Comparator[T] and maintains the order. 
>   Parameters: num - the number of
>   top elements to return comp - the comparator that defines the order
>   Returns: an array of top elements

or

> **takeOrdered**
>  java.util.List takeOrdered(int num) 
> Returns the first K
>   elements from this RDD using the natural ordering for T while maintain
>   the order. 
> Parameters: num - the number of top elements to return
>   
> Returns: an array of top elements

so you could do

```
List<String> sortedLines = lines.takeOrdered(lines.count());
ctx.stop();
```

since RDD are distributed and shuffeled for each transformation, it's kinda useless to sort when it's still in RDD form, because when sorted RDD transformed, it will be shuffled (cmiiw)

but take a look at [JavaPairRDD.sortByKey()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#sortByKey())

Answer (score 1):

Try collect():

```
List<String> list = lines.collect();
Collections.sort(list);
```